# Where should I put delete statements in my code to remove the memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

There is a memory leak that I see in Valgrind in my C++ program. I'm wondering where I should place delete statements to remote it. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void showFloatArray(float f1[10]) {
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << " " << f1[i];
    cout << endl;
}

float *getFloatArrayOne() {
    float *floatArray = new float[10];
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
        floatArray[i] = (float) i;
    return(floatArray);
}

float *getFloatArrayTwo() {
    float myFloatArray[10];
    float *floatArray = myFloatArray;
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
        floatArray[i] = (float) i;
    return(floatArray);
}

int main()
{
    float *f1 = getFloatArrayOne();
    float *f2 = getFloatArrayTwo();
    showFloatArray(f1);
    showFloatArray(f2);
}
```

Comment: Is there any indentation to be had?

Comment: You shouldn't have a memory leak int he first place. Don't write bad code. Don't create leaks. Don't say `new`.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah my bad, fixing it now.

Comment: @KerrekSB This is a homework problem, sorry. It was made to have a memory leak.

Comment: Then fix it at the point where the leak was created. Don't try to clean up afterwards, that's a losing battle with no mental gratification.

Comment: @user3182252 - `This is a homework problem`  So how do you want to solve it?  By putting in ugly `new[]/delete[]` code or use better constructs in place of `new[]/delete[]`?  Either way, the leaks are gone.

Comment: @hyde: There's definitely a memory leak. See `new float[10];`.

Comment: You're also invoking *undefined behavior* by returning and evaluating the address of an automatic variable in `getFloatArrayTwo`.

Comment: @user3182252 - As *WhosCraig* pointed out, you have another issue by returning the address of an automatic variable.  The solution to both the memory leak and this further issue is to use `std::vector<float>`.

Comment: ... or in the case of your fixed-length arrays, `std::array<float,10>`, or bury your arrays in a structure (effectively what `std::array` does). i know it doesn't help you with your homework problem, but honestly, the solution to your *real* problem is not using hand-rolled dynamic allocation mechanics where they're not needed (and they're *rarely* needed) in the first place. Following that, fixing your "leak" would be trivial (because you wouldn't have one in the first place; [example here](http://ideone.com/Tp6plX)).

Comment: You should probably just use std containers and smart pointers and call it a day.

Comment: This is the problem with the institutes. They still follow the old way of teaching c++ and the tools/software they have is way too old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you create a pointer with `new` then you have to make sure you call `delete` on that pointer before the program ends.

For example:

```
int main()
{
    Object * obj = new Object;
    return 0; //leaky program! 
}


int main()
{
    Object * obj = new Object;
    delete obj;
    return 0; //non-leaky program! 
}
```

Comment: In the context of valgrind, the first one will show un-freed heap blocks, and the second one won't.

Comment: This answer is pretty poor for not bothering to mention `delete[]`, which the OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

Quick re-write

Better to get caller to make allocations.  Caller then knows to allocate and de-allocate.  If your function (eg a library) allocates, then caller might be in doubt about whether objects must be de-allocated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

// remove fixed size restriction on function
void print_array(float* f, size_t size) {
  for (size_t i=0; i < size; i++)
    cout << " " << f[i];
  cout << endl;
}

// pass in array
float* getFloatArrayOne(float f[], size_t size) {
  for (size_t i=0; i < size; i++)
    f[i] = (float)i;
  return f;
}

// pass in ptr - caller responsible for allocation and de-allocating
float *getFloatArrayTwo(float* f, size_t size) {
  for (size_t i=0; i < size; i++)
    *(f+i) = (float)i;  // dereference pointer + offset method 
  return f;
}

// You can use any algorithm you like to generate numbers
struct myincrementer {
  myincrementer(float startval) : n_(startval) {}
  float operator()() { return ++n_; }  // change to n_++ to start printing first value
  float n_;
};

int main()
{
  const int size = 10;
  float* floatArray = new float[size]();
  float *f1 = getFloatArrayOne(floatArray, size);

  float myFloatArray[size] = {0};
  float *f2 = getFloatArrayTwo(myFloatArray, size);
  print_array(f1, size);
  print_array(f2, size);
  delete [] floatArray;  // note [] form

  // More advanced approach
  vector<float> vec;
  myincrementer myi(0.0);
  generate_n(back_inserter(vec), 10, myi);
  std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

'Modern' C++ typically avoids leaks by not using `new` and `delete` directly, instead delegating the management of resources like memory to objects that handle them internally.

However since this is homework it seems worthwhile to learn not just good practices which eliminate problems, but the technical details of what a leak is and the formal requirements to avoid a leak, independent of any particular method for effectively carrying out those requirements.

So here it is: A memory leak occurs when a pointer value is returned by a successful call to an allocation function and no subsequent call to the correct deallocation function is made using the value returned by the allocation function. That is, a leak occurs when you allocate memory and then fail to deallocate it.

Allocations by `malloc()` must be deallocated with `free()`. Allocations by `new` must be deallocated with `delete`. Allocations by `new[]` must be deallocated with `delete[]`.

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int)); // C code

if (x) {
  // allocation succeeded, you can use the resource and you should free() it
  // ... use
  free(x);
}
```

```
int *y = new int;
delete y;
```

```
int *z = new int[10];
delete [] z;
```

### In Practice

So fixing or avoiding memory leaks requires 'merely' that your program call the deallocation function for every successful allocation. The challenge however, is that this is difficult to do in an arbitrary or ad-hoc manner. In order to avoid leaks in practice you need to establish patterns of allocation and deallocation that can be easily managed and verified.

So here are some pointers to get you started on learning about the practicalities of resource management:

The basic practice for managing resource across many languages is to define "ownership semantics" for specific resources. You define rules for determining what part of the program is responsible for any particular allocated resource, and rules for how responsibility for a particular resource may be handed off from one part of the program to another.

Typically ownership semantics are defined such that the part of a program that allocates a resource is responsible for it. That may seem obvious, but there are alternatives. E.g. a program could designate a single entity that takes responsibility for cleaning up everything, and then the rest of the program just allocates at will and has nothing to do with clean-up. But more commonly whatever allocates a resource takes responsibility for it.

For example a function that allocates some dynamic memory to perform its task also frees that memory when its done:

```
void foo(int n) {
  int *arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
  // ...
  free(arr)
}
```

Another way to 'take responsibility' for an allocated resource is to be explicit about about requirements for resource management when resources are passed off. For example a function which needs to allocate memory and pass that memory back to the caller may specify "callers of `foo()` must call `free_foo(foo_results)` when the foo results are no longer needed."

```
foo_t *foo() {
  foo_t *f = malloc(sizeof(foo_t));
  // ...
  return f;
}

void free_foo(foo_t *f) {
  free(f);
}
```

#### Exceptions

For correct resource management whatever rules of ownership semantics have been designed must be followed in all circumstances. There's one language feature supported by C++ that has historically given some people trouble, making them think they'd correctly handled resource management responsibilities when in fact they hadn't. This feature is exceptions.

I won't go into details about exceptions, but it suffices to say that they are the reason that code such as:

```
doSomething();
cleanup();
```

is incorrect. And once you learn the idiomatic C++ way to manage resources it should be absolutely obvious that the above is wrong, without you even needing to know what `doSomething()` does. (One common criticism of exceptions is that they require you to know if `doSomething()` might throw an exception in order to know how to do the cleanup, which could require manually examining a huge amount of code. But since one *can* do the cleanup correctly without knowing if `doSomething()` throws, that criticism is incorrect.)

#### C++

In C++ a specific practice for managing resources has been developed, called *RAII*, for *Resource Acquisition Is Initialization*. It's reliable and easy to use, and correctly handles circumstances such as exceptions. Under RAII a resource is represented as an object, and the correct ownership semantics are encoded into the object's special functions: its destructor, copy/move constructors, and copy and move assignment operators.

Thus you acquire a resource by initializing an object of the right type and you access the resource through that object. If the resource can be copied or moved then you can copy or move the object. If the resource is fundamentally not copyable or moveable then the object is non-copyable or non-moveable, and trying to copy or move it will produce a compiler error.

Some resource managing, RAII types in the C++ standard library are:

- `std::array`: a template class that manages a static, in-place memory buffer, presented as an array of objects
- `std::vector`: a template class that manages dynamic memory, presented as a resizable array of objects.
- `std::string`: a template class that manages static and/or dynamic memory, presented as a resizable array of `char`.
- `std::shared_ptr`: a template class that implements reference counting ownership semantics. By default the resource is a dynamically allocated object, but this can be configured.
- `std::unique_ptr`: a template class that implements unique ownership semantics. By default the resource is a dynamically allocated object or array, but this can be configured.

For more info on resource management in C++ you can visit http://exceptionsafecode.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just delete f1, as the main function terminates. The first one is allocated on the heap dynamically and it remains allocated though-out execution, and it needs to be deleted. As for the second one, you declare it statically (on the stack), and when the function getFloatArrayTwo() terminates, it deallocates already the vector, deleting it again my result a runtime double delete error. After showFloatArray(f2); you should put delete f1, and the leaks should dissapear.

Hope this to be of help.